# Tailwind CSS: Conflict Between Multiple Config Files

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

When using two separate Tailwind CSS config files for different pages and customizing classes like spacing in both config files, a conflict occurs. The styles from both config files are active simultaneously, and some classes are being used from the wrong config file.

What I Tried:

I created two separate Tailwind CSS config files, one for Page A and one for Page B.
I customized spacing classes in both config files to have different values.
I built and served Page A with its Tailwind CSS config in reactjs.
I navigated to Page B with its Tailwind CSS config.
Expected Behavior:

I expected that each page would use its respective Tailwind CSS config file without interference from other pages' configurations.

Comment: Why do you choose this complex approach? What other frontend framework is page B using?

Comment: you should add screenshots of your config files to your question, so that it's easier to help you locate possible errors

Comment: @UdoE. The project presented a unique challenge. We needed to have two configuration files: one for the new design system and the other for legacy pages. Until the legacy part is updated to the new design system, we have to use both configurations.

Comment: @Airah I just used this link https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-2 and added some spacing configurations like this :
  spacing: {'1': '4px','2': '8px'}
Now, I want to use this new configuration on a new page, while keeping the default Tailwind values on other old pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.